# Facing error while installing react-redux@5.0.7

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, web-deployment

These are my current dependencies:

```
react": "^17.0.1",

"react-dom": "^17.0.1",

"react-popper": "^1.3.7",

"redux": "^3.7.2"
```

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtXFu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As the [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux) suggests:

"As of React Native 0.18, React Redux 5.x should work with React Native. If you have any issues with React Redux 5.x on React Native, `run npm ls react` and make sure you don’t have a duplicate React installation in your node_modules. We recommend that you use npm@3.x which is better at avoiding these kinds of issues."